# Seeding Error: "The instance of entity type cannot be tracked because another instance with the same key value for is already being tracked"

Tags: c#, entity-framework, web, asp.net-core-mvc, seed

I get an error while seeding the data.

Model:

```
public class Federation
{        
    public string FName { get; set; }        
}
```

Configuration:

```
public class FederationConfiguration : IEntityTypeConfiguration<Federation>
{        
    public void Configure(EntityTypeBuilder<Federation> builder)
    {
        builder.HasKey(t => t.FName);
        builder.Property(t => t.FName)
            .HasMaxLength(20)
            .IsRequired();
    }
}
```

In the DbContext

```
protected override void OnModelCreating(ModelBuilder builder)
{
    builder.ApplyConfigurationsFromAssembly(Assembly.GetExecutingAssembly());            
    base.OnModelCreating(builder);
}
```

In the seeding method, I just try to add sample data to the database:

```
public static class SeedFederations
{        
    public static async Task SeedFederationsDataAsync(ApplicationDbContext context)
    {
        if (context.Federations.Any())
        {
            return;   // DB has been seeded
        }
        context.Federations.AddRange(
            new Federation { FName = "FIFA" },
            new Federation { FName = "UEFA" },
            new Federation { FName = "UEFA" },
            new Federation { FName = "AFC" }
         );
        context.SaveChanges();
        await context.SaveChangesAsync();
    }
}
```

I have tried to seed another set of data to the database:

```
public static async Task SeedAppLicationData(ApplicationDbContext context)
{
    await SeedCountries.SeedCountriesDataAsync(context);
    await SeedTeamTypes.SeedTeamTypesDataAsync(context);
    await SeedTeams.SeedTeamsDataAsync(context);
    await SeedBettingTypes.SeedBettingTypesDataAsync(context);
    await SeedFederations.SeedFederationsDataAsync(context); // only error here
}
```

Other seeding is Ok only the last get a problem. It does not seed data and when I set the debug I get this message:

> The instance of entity type 'Federation' cannot be tracked because another instance with the same key value for {'FName'} is already being tracked. When attaching existing entities, ensure that only one entity instance with a given key value is attached. C...

I have tried: modify field name to make sure not the same with others table.

Please help me.

Thanks

Comment: Just to check, you did it with different values? You enter "UEFA" twice in the seed data, perhaps the duplicate keys give an issue?

Answer (score 0):

Your DB Context is being shared by multiple requests, meaning that the entity you're editing has been tracked already.

This is likely because your repository service is a Singleton rather than Scoped, and so your DB Context is being reused with the entity being tracked when it's pulled out, and then put back in to the same instance of the DB Context.

What you should be doing instead is having a Scoped Repository, which means that a new instance will be created for each request. Likewise, you will also have a per-request DB Context.

When you register your service it will be using services.AddSingleton<..>

Change this to services.AddScoped<..>, when you inject it into your controller you will then get a new instance per request and your updates should work fine.

Or you still have problems after trying, you can try the following methods, for reference only:

```
  public static async Task SeedFederationsDataAsync(ApplicationDbContext context)
    {
        try
        {   
          if (context.Federations.Any())
            {
                return;   // DB has been seeded
            }
            context.Federations.AddRange(
                new Federation { FName = "FIFA" },
                new Federation { FName = "UEFA" },
                new Federation { FName = "UEFA" },
                new Federation { FName = "AFC" }
             );
            context.SaveChanges();
            await context.SaveChangesAsync();
        }
        catch (Exception e)
        {
             // handle correct exception
             // log error
             return false;
        }
    }
```